# Select N Row in Oracle

Tags: oracle, rank, dense-rank

Suppose we are having the following data:

```
Key Value Desired Rank
--- ----- ------------
P1    0.6            2    
P1    0.6            2    
P1    0.6            2    
P2    0.8            1
P2    0.8            1
P3    0.6            3
P3    0.6            3
```

I want to select Distinct **Keys** ordered by **Value DESC** to be displayed in a grid that supports pagination.

I don’t know how to generate rank as the values displayed in **Desired Rank column**. So that I can paginate correctly over the data set

When I tried to use: DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY value), the result was

```
Key Value   DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY value)
--- ----- ------------
P1    0.6            2    
P1    0.6            2
P1    0.6            2    
P2    0.8            1
P2    0.8            1
P3    0.6            2    
P3    0.6            2
```

When I try to select the first two keys “rank between 1 and 2” I receive back 3 keys. And this ruins the required pagination mechanism.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: "I don’t know how to generate rank as the values displayed in Desired Rank column." Neither do I. You say that you want them ordered by value descending (which is what the second set of data provides). Could you give some examples where each key ("P1", "P2"...) has different values and what you expect in those situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the distinct keys and values, why not use distinct?

```
select distinct
  t.Key,
  t.Value
from
  YourTable t
order by
  t.value
```

Do you actualle need the rank?

If you do, you still could

```
select distinct
  t.Key,
  t.Value,
  dense_rank() over () order by (t.Value, t.Key) as Rank
from
  YourTable t
order by
  t.value
```

This whould work without the distinct as well.

Answer (score 1):

> 'When I try to select the first two
>   keys “rank between 1 and 2” I receive
>   back 3 keys.'

That is because you are ordering just by VALUE, so all KEYS with the same value are assigned the same rank.  So you need to include the KEY in the ordering clause.  Like this:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY key ASC, value DESC)
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the desired result by this : DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY value DESC, key ASC)  , So that the rows are displayed ordered by value if it is equal, the key decides the order